# Increase the signal's time axis length in xilinx ise simulator

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am working on a project(VHDL). I have generated a test bench of the top module having `clk` and `reset` signals. When I don't use reset in the process in the test bench my simulator shows the clock signals all the way up to 1000 ns (desired here) but as soon as I introduce reset, it's length reduce to 160 ns. I am unable to understand the behaviour.
Here is the first test bench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
ENTITY toplevel_tb1 IS
END toplevel_tb1;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF toplevel_tb1 IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT pc_ins_cu_top
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         reset : IN  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal reset : std_logic := '1';

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: pc_ins_cu_top PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          reset => reset
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  
            --reset <= '0';
      wait for clk_period*100;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

In my second test bench, I am just uncommenting the line with `reset <= '0'` in the `stim_proc : process`

here are the images :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the console for errors, assertions  with severity=failure etc. Something - probably an error - is halting the simulation early

Comment: This could be telling you your pc_ins_cu_top has a process that doesn't suspend around 165 ns following the reset and simulation time is not advancing as a result. The problem is not present in the portion of your code you have displayed here, it's not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note your not stopping the testbench clock which says you're limiting the simulation time else where.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sir, I checked the console. There is no error.

Comment: @user1155120 I think I get your point. I am going to check my top module. Thanks!